# How do you give cells in a TableView a unique reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm still very new to iOS development, so bear with me.

I've got a TableView using static cells to contain options (click to check), I am able to select the cells fine. I'd like to assign a value (identifier) to each cell, so that when a cell is selected or de-selected I can add/remove it from an array. Then, once the editing has finished, use the references stored in the array to update the respective CoreData attributes.

My google skills have failed me today, so a push in the right direction would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSIndexPath_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is the best tool for that! It will be unique for the selected cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"%i", indexPath.section);
}
```

And I think you need this:

```
[yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

to get reference .

Comment: I've got something like this setup at the moment, retrieving the row ID isn't a problem. I was more wondering how I'd be able to link the row ID to an attribute within CoreData. Unless, as it's static, I assume that Row 1 is always going to be related to Attribute X.

Comment: And whats there in your coredata? Be more specific to your question

Comment: I have an entity called 'User'. This user has a number of boolean options, which are represented by the checkable cells. 

E.g. Entity Attributes
wifi_enabled (bool)
data_enabled (bool)

These options are represented as checkable cells in a table view. They aren't the same names, purely used for example purposes. 

The checkable cells will have to relate to these options. E.g. Cell 1 (id 0) refers to one option, Cell 2 (id 1) refers to another option. When the changes are saved, I need to link the checked rows to their respective attributes.

Comment: You will be using an array loaded from core data as datasource for the cells, right? Why dont you make the respective changes in the array? you have the indexPath.row as the reference to index and later update the core data table with this!

Comment: This is where my lack of experience kicks in. I wasn't using a datasource to produce the cells, the creation of the cells was done manually.

Comment: First change the method you are following, use datasource methods. Avoid hardcoding

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to. I'm not entirely sure how to go about it. It's set up as a static table at the moment. These options aren't the only items on the page, there are other text fields and such too. Unsure as to how I would dynamically pull the text fields and then separate the options from them, as they're all part of the same entity.

Comment: I'll have a play around. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add details regarding a cell when a cell is selected within method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And for removing the details when a cell is deselected in delegate method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hold a reference to each cell. The data source should be a mirror of what is showing on the screen. You can know what should be removed added by using:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

or when you deselect it:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

With `NSIndexPath` you can then know what has been selected/deselected:

Answer (score 0):

Where as I understand you want to select/deselect rows of `UITableView` and after deletig any row from table you want that it should be removed from DB also.

you can use the method -

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if(editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        {

            [code to remove object from db on particular property];     

         }

     }
```

Now the code to remove particular record/row from DB is -

```
-(void)deleteUserForId:(NSString *)user_id
{
    NSManagedObject *statusTag=[self getUserForUserid:user_id];
    NSError *error;

    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:statusTag];
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {

    }

}

-(UserData*)getUserForUserid:(NSString *)user_id
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [self getBasicRequestForEntityName:@"UserData"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"user_id== %@",user_id];


    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    [request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];  

    UserData *userInfoObj = nil;
    if (!error && [results count] > 0)
    {

        userInfoObj = [results objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    return userInfoObj;
}
```